# Lua get number type

Tags: lua

In Lua, using the type function on any number always returns 'number'. Is there a function which can tell you whether the Lua interpreter is using a 32 bit floats, 64 bit doubles, integers or something else for the number type?

I tried to write a function like this:

```lua
function numbertype()
  local rational = 5 / 2

  if rational == 2 then
    -- equals 2
    return 'int'
  else
    -- about 2.5
    return 'double' -- but could it be a 32 bit float or something else?
  end
end

print(numbertype())
```

It can't yet detect the difference between floats, doubles and unknown types. How can I query to see if Lua's number type is equivalent to an int, float or double in Lua's interpreter? I would like it to work in pure Lua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure Lua cannot inquire about such things from the interpreter. Since the ability of the interpreter to use different types is pretty free-form (you can pick any floating-point or integral type), the only way to expose this to Lua would be to have the interpreter coded to anticipate every possible type of number that it could be compiled with.

In general, you shouldn't bother caring. Applications that use something other than doubles are rare at best. Even LuaJIT, which has to deal with ARM and their terrible floating-point math, still hides its ability to use integer math effectively as an optimization; Lua code can't tell the difference.

Which is as it should be.

Comment: Although not exactly pure Lua, would it be possible to read the size of the number in the bytecode header returned by string.dump()?

Comment: @user1721424: You would need fairly intimate knowledge of what gets dumped from that function. And even then, that *might* only give you a size (it might always use 8 bytes regardless of the C datatype); you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between a `float` and an `int`.

Comment: @user1721424: This seems like an ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're trying to do something that you think you need to do this to solve, but you haven't told us what you're trying to do that you think you need to do this for.

Comment: I agree, I'm probably approaching the answer wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I agree about the fact that you should not care much about datatype in pure lua, although applications using floats are not rare (majority of games use it, so are other 3d applications since physics/math libraries are mostly based on floats, and gpu support for float is still fairly limited).

Comment: @catflier: "*applications using floats are not rare*" Do you have any evidence that most games that use Lua recompile Lua to use floats instead of doubles? Also: "*gpu support for float is still fairly limited*" I think you meant *doubles*. Also, GPU support for *tables* and other Lua data structures is far more limited. You're not running Lua code on GPUs.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right i meant doubles, my bad. And by applications using float I wanted to point about the application in general, not only the lua bindings.

Comment: @catflier: What other applications in general use is irrelevant to the topic at hand. Lua uses *doubles*, and most people don't recompile their Lua library to use floats just because they use floats outside of Lua.

Comment: The approach *is* wrong here but you *can* find out a lot about the number type from the bytecode header. To tell the difference between float and int there is a boolean field after the number size (see http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lundump.c.html#luaU_header or my own parser here https://github.com/catwell/lualua/blob/master/src/binparser.lua#L189).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Lua 5.1 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2), numbers are only double-precision floating-point numbers. To use another type, Lua must be recompiled with a modified `luaconf.h`.

Comment: Yes, but I want to ask the interpreter which number type it has been compiled for.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the following workarround. Calculate number%1. If the remainder is 0 than it is most likely something like an integer number.

Answer (score 0):

From the helpful sources in catwell's comment, I wrote a function which can return the number type based on the bytecode header. The function is useful, but **it should never be used** because it only works for a specific interpreter. It would need to be **entirely rewritten** for lua 5.2 or luajit, which creates unnecessary burdens for code reuse.

Instead, lua scripts should be written independent of the interpreter or number type used.

For completeness, here it is function:

```lua
-- only work in Lua 5.1
function numbertype()
  local headertypes = {
    ['\4\1'] = 'int32',
    ['\8\1'] = 'int64',
    ['\4\0'] = 'float32',
    ['\8\0'] = 'float64'}

  -- returns nil if the type is something else
  return headertypes[string.dump(function () end):sub(11,12)]
end
```